# Editing Core Data List Item Appends Instead of Adding

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, edit, objectcontext

My To-Do app already had add and delete (from Core Data) functionality. That worked perfect. My problem is that my attempt to add editing is malfunctioning.

**Behavior**

I coded it so if the user taps a task in the table, it sets that task's cell index path, title, and description to variables and passes them to the modal ViewController for editing. The modal view presents and those passed variables then populate the textfields. The user can then edit the existing content and hit save which runs some save code (I'll share below). The modal view is dismissed, the table data reloaded and the cell appears just where it was before but with updated content. THIS ALL WORKS. The malfunction happens upon a close/full shutdown of the app and reopening it. Suddenly the original task is back BUT a copy with the edits is appended to the bottom of the list.

**Question**

Why is my code doing this and how can I get the edited title and description to save and load correctly?

**Information**

My core data file name is: CD_Model
My entity name is: TodayTask
My attribute names are: 1) "name" 2) "desc"

**Code**

I included a lot of my code in case the error is somewhere I don't expect. However, I added bold to the headers of the two snippets I think are causing the problems. The error is revealed only upon the viewDidLoad running (first code snippet below). But the error may actually happen in the last snippet, the save function.

Imports & Global variables:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var todayTaskList = [NSManagedObject]()
var passingEdit = false
```

**Declaration and viewDidLoad of main VC, which contains the table:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
//***** ----- ***** ------ ***** ----- ***** ----- *****
//Initial Setup
//***** ----- ***** ------ ***** ----- ***** ----- *****

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //This loads the list from Core Data
    //1
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"TodayTask")

    //3
    var error: NSError?
    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        todayTaskList = results
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }

    //This provides a variable height for each row
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0
}
```

Code for creating the table:

```
//***** ----- ***** ------ ***** ----- ***** ----- *****
//Table View & Cell Setup
//***** ----- ***** ------ ***** ----- ***** ----- *****
@IBOutlet weak var name_Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var desc_Label: UILabel!

//Tells the table how many rows it should render
//*Looks to the Core Data NSObject to count tasks
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return todayTaskList.count
}

//Creates the individual cells. If the above function returns 3, this runs 3 times
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //Setup variables
    let cellIdentifier = "BasicCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    let task = todayTaskList[indexPath.row]

    //Create table cell with values from Core Data attribute lists
    cell.nameLabel!.text = task.valueForKey("name") as? String
    cell.descLabel!.text = task.valueForKey("desc") as? String

    //Make sure the row heights adjust properly
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0

    return cell
}
```

Code run when an existing task is tapped:

```
//***** ----- ***** ------ ***** ----- ***** ----- *****
//Functions
//***** ----- ***** ------ ***** ----- ***** ----- *****

//Action: Edit list item on row tap
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    passingEdit = true

    performSegueWithIdentifier("modalToEditor", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "modalToEditor") && passingEdit == true {

        //Assign selection to a variable 'currentCell'
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! CustomTableViewCell;

        //Set cell text into variables to pass to editor
        var cellNameForEdit = currentCell.nameLabel!.text
        var cellDescForEdit = currentCell.descLabel.text

        //Pass values to EditorView
        var editorVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EditorView;
        editorVC.namePassed = cellNameForEdit
        editorVC.descPassed = cellDescForEdit
        editorVC.indexOfTap = indexPath


    }
}
```

Declaration of modal Editor VC, variables passed from main VC are set:

```
class EditorView: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

//Declare outlets and vars
@IBOutlet var txtTask: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtDesc: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var addSave: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var cancel: UIButton!

var namePassed: String!
var descPassed: String!
var indexOfTap: NSIndexPath!

//Initial Functions
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.txtTask.becomeFirstResponder()

    if passingEdit == true {
        txtTask.text = namePassed
        txtDesc.text = descPassed
        addSave.setTitle("Save", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    else {
        addSave.setTitle("Add", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

**Function run upon hitting the save button:**

```
func modRec(nameValue: String, descValue: String, indexPos: NSIndexPath) {

    //1
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //2
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TodayTask", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let todayTask = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    //3
    todayTask.setValue(nameValue, forKey: "name")
    todayTask.setValue(descValue, forKey: "desc")

    //4
    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }
    //5
    todayTaskList[indexPos.row] = todayTask
    managedContext.save(nil)


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the following changes in your code.
I have added the oldnamevale and olddescvalue as parameter in the function that can be used for predicate. You have to pass these values.

```
func modRec(oldnameValue: String, olddescValue: String,newnameValue: String, newdescValue: String, indexPos: NSIndexPath) {

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TodayTask")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", oldnameValue)

    if let fetchResults = appDel.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [NSManagedObject] {
      if fetchResults.count != 0{

        var managedObject = fetchResults[0]
        managedObject.setValue(newdescValue, forKey: "desc")
        managedObject.setValue(newnameValue, forKey: "name")

      context.save(nil)
      }
   }

}
```

If you want execute query using name and desc then make the following changes in the above code

```
let Predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", oldnameValue)
let Predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "desc = %@", olddescValue)

var compound = NSCompoundPredicate.andPredicateWithSubpredicates([Predicate1!, Predicate2!])
fetchRequest.predicate = compound
```

Hope this might be helpful.

Comment: It was. Pretty much just cut/paste. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your `modRec` method, you create a new `TodayTask` object:

```
let todayTask = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
```

and then you replace the object at the relevant index in your `todayTaskList` array:

```
todayTaskList[indexPos.row] = todayTask
```

But the previous object, whose values you are amending, still exists.  It's no longer in your array, but it is still in the Core Data store.  When you reload your table view, it uses the `todayTaskList` array to populate the rows, and you see what you expect.  But when you close and reopen the app, the `todayTaskList` array itself gets rebuilt by fetching from the CoreData store.  Because both the old `todayTask` and the new one exist, they are both added to the array, and consequently your table view shows both.

To fix this, I would restructure your code slightly:

1. Amend the `EditorView` view controller: rather than having vars for each of the attributes passed to it, use a var for the complete `NSManagedObject`.  You can then populate the text fields using the attributes of that NSMO.  (You will need to amend the `prepareForSegue` code accordingly.  If you are adding a new `TodayTask` then create the NSManagedObject, and add it to your array, before segueing to EditorView).
2. Then, in your `modRec` method, you do not need to insert a new `TodayTask` object, you can just set the attributes of the NSMO var.
3. Since you amend the existing NSMO, rather than inserting a new one, you do not need to replace the object in the `todayTaskList` array.

Since you no longer have to update the `todayTaskList` array from within the `EditorView`, it does not need to be global (which, as a matter of good practice, you should avoid doing wherever possible).  It can just be a var in your main view controller.  (It should also be possible to avoid `passingEdit` being global).

Comment: I picked Karlos's answer because I didn't know how to write the code for your answer and his was cut/paste in two minutes. Your answer is a wonderful explanation of how my array is faking me into believing my Core Data store is changed. No one else answered that part. You also peaked my curiosity as to why I should avoid global variables, what about it is a bad practice? If you add the code so a dope like me can implement it, that'd definitely make yours the best post. Regardless, sincere thanks.

Comment: @DaveG Globals go against the object oriented programming principle of encapsulation - objects should be "black boxes" whose internal data and methods are hidden from other objects, except through a well-defined interface.  In your case, the `todayTaskList` array is the datasource for the table view, and so should really be hidden from other objects.  Because it is global, it can be accessed by all other objects, so your EditorView controller can amend it when necessary.  But there is a danger in this: Suppose you were adding new `todayTasks` by downloading them from a server....

Comment: @DaveG .... your table view controller might not know that the array was being updated, and the table view would be out of sync with your array.  Or if you work as part of a team, one of your colleagues might write another view controller elsewhere in the app that messes with your array.  This makes debugging a nightmare.  So my recommendation would be to avoid them where possible - there are other design patterns that you can use (singletons, delegates, ...).  But I don't mean to preach - it may be that globals are the easiest/best solution for you, at least for the time being.

Comment: pbasdf, as terrible as it sounds, I didn't know any of that. Following best practices is a habit I want to have so going forward I'll try to avoid them. Might even circle back and try to just pass those variables to the VCs that need them. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with modRec function. You should modify the Core data values using predicate.Check the example given below or [This link](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-2/) or [This tutorial](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-2/). It might be helpful for you.

```
func saveLoginData(accessToken: String, userName: String) {
    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LoginData")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userName = %@", userName)

    if let fetchResults = appDel.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [NSManagedObject] {
       if fetchResults.count != 0{

          var managedObject = fetchResults[0]
          managedObject.setValue(accessToken, forKey: "accessToken")

          context.save(nil)
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I had this code in last night and was trying to adapt it in but wasn't able to.  In my case, what should I put for the predicate format? That is, what should I use for "userName = %@". As a reminder, my core data Entity name is 'TodayTask', attributes are 'name' and 'desc', and I set var todayTaskList = [NSManagedObject]()

Answer (score 0):

1,  You should implement the `FetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods on your tableview and don't try managing your own list - this is not the correct way to do things and will result in problems and records not showing up properly in your UI.

2. You just need to update the attributes on the original entity you retrieved.  Your save code is creating a new record.

So in your editor view add a property which is set to the original object, rather than each property.

Now in your edit view when the user hits save just update the properties on the original task object and call `ManagedObjectContext.Save()` - too easy.

Pass the `ManagedObject` and `ManagedObjectContext` values to EditorView

```
var editorVC = segue.destinationViewController as! EditorView;
editorVC.task = selectedTask
editorVC.moc = managedContext
```

Edit view save - just update the original task properties (a ManagedObject)

```
       this.task.name = nameField.Text
       this.task.desc = descField.Text

       // That's it or commit to disk by calling MOC.Save
       try {
            this.moc.Save()
       }
```

Comment: You can find working examples here http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: Duncan, thanks. I'm trying your link and code now. Can you clarify what you meant by "Don't try managing your own list"? I'm brand new to Core Data, just started two days ago. What am I doing that qualifies as trying to manage my own list? You provided code to add that I presume does not break rule #1, but is there code I should remove?

Comment: OK well that's good because you will avoid wasting a lot of time.  Core Data provides a way to display a list of data in a table view such that adding, removing or editing any item will automatically update the UI view, even if updates are done by a background thread. Here is a link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Comment: My sample app has an example of this - just not in Swift, in Objective-C.  But it is very similar in structure.  Don't bother learning Obj-C though.